# how to build a object with VARIANT* pvarItems

Tags: c++

How to write a unit test to invoke the below function Calculate? Or says how build a parameter VARIANT* pvarItems with number 2 and 0.8?
Please note this parameter is a pointer!
Thanks.

```
STDMETHODIMP MyCom::Calculate(VARIANT* pvarItems)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

if (V_VT(pvarItems) == (VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT))
{
    SAFEARRAY *psa = V_ARRAY(pvarItems);

    LONG lb, ub;
    hr = SafeArrayGetLBound(psa, 1, &lb);
    hr = SafeArrayGetUBound(psa, 1, &ub);

    for (LONG i = lb; i <= ub; i++)
    {
        VARIANT out;
        VariantInit(&out);

        hr = SafeArrayGetElement(psa, &i, &out);

        switch (V_VT(&out))
        {
        case VT_I4:
            printf("Item number %d, Value is %d\n", i, V_I4(&out));
            break;
        case VT_BSTR:
            printf("Item number %d, Value is %ls\n", i, V_BSTR(&out));
            break;
        default:
            printf("Item number %d, Sample not coded for this data type\n", i);
        }

        VariantClear(&out);
    }
} 
return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: This member takes a VARIANT-hosted SAFEARRAY of VARIANT. That sums up what has to be built to invoke it any chance of success. The actual function is poorly coded, as the only validity checking done is on the initial input argument. The `hr` status values are completely ignored, and the function always returns `S_OK`, so you could pass *any* variant (including a VT_NULL) into this member and it will report success.

Comment: Anyone can help me?